# Executing manual (Webjobs) from ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, manual, azure-webjobssdk

I have a project in ASP.net MVC 4 and work with Webjobs and it works wonderfully.
But now I want implement a process that starts the webjob directly (manual), because I have them working every 5 minutes. That is ok, but now I want have this function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your MVC4 Controller action you can put a message on a queue and have a function triggered on this queue message.

Comment: You can give me a link where explaing this please, sorry but im new in this.